# How to make Bootstrap 4 Cover Example work?

Tags: templates, bootstrapping, cover

I'm a beginner at this. How do I make [Bootstrap 4 cover example](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/cover/) work correctly so I can edit it myself?

I've tried downloading the source, take bootstrap.min.css and .js and place them in my main folder, then View Page Source to get the template's code and pasted it into my index.html. All I see is plain Bootstrap text when I preview it... What steps am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fix the paths in the html file.

```
 <link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

should be

```
 <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

in case the css file and the index.html are in the same folder.
The same holds for `bootstrap.min.js` at the bottom of the html.
Furthermore you need the [`cover.css`](http://view-source:http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/cover/#) and save it in the same directory as the html.

Comment: Thank you! Turned out, I didn't create a CSS file for cover.css, which I didn't know was clickable on the page source. You definitely led me on the right track.

Comment: And, to add the image..?

Answer (score 1):

To add the image add the following code to your body tag in cover.scss

```
background: image-url('background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
```

Comment: I modified your answer to get it to work for me in the css.
`background-image: url('image.jpg');`
  `background-repeat: no-repeat;`
  `background-position: center center;`

Answer (score 0):

The actual source code, along with all other bootstrap example are here. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/site/content/docs/4.3/examples/cover

The url may change as bootstrap get's updated